# How to modify strings.xml file at runtime

Tags: android, string, localization

I will get localized data dynamically only.

Is there a way to update `strings.xml` file at runtime in Android? Can we add new string to the file at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can we add new string to the file at runtime?

No. You can create a database of translations and maintain that database. Add new translations on the fly to the database and read the values from there.

Comment: any sample implementation for this

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I did a library that does almost it, you can check it here:
https://github.com/jcminarro/Philology